# Как сопоставить ячейки одной строки, с другой? в Excel

Tags: функции, excel

Имеется таблица Excel (пока 3 столбца):

- в первом столбце (A) — список;
- во втором (B) — тот же список, но перемешанный;
- в третьем столбце (С) — инфа, которую нужно сопоставить.

В столбцах B, C лежит нужная инфа (на одной строке). Её нужно присоединить к уже имеющемуся списку(столбец A). Как присоединить BС к А?

Примеры

Как сейчас:

```
A    B    C  
1111 3333 текст 3   
2222 4444 текст 4   
3333 1111 текст 1   
4444 2222 текст 2
```

Как хотим

```
A    B    C       D  
1111 3333 текст 3 текст 1  
2222 4444 текст 4 текст 2  
3333 1111 текст 1 текст 3   
4444 2222 текст 2 текст 4
```

Answer (score 0):

В столбец D вставьте следующую формулу =ВПР(A1;B:C;2;0)
Пример:
A       B       C       D
1111    3333    текст 1 текст 3 
2222    4444    текст 2 текст 4 
3333    1111    текст 3 текст 1 
4444    2222    текст 4 текст 2

Comment: Возвращает #Н/Д... Не может найти значение при поиске по B:C

Comment: Странно. Такая ошибка может возникнуть, если Excel, например, в столбце A значение 1111 отображает как текст, а в столбце B отображается как численное значение. Нужно чтобы форматы данных в столбцах A и B совпадали.

Comment: В столбце А значение 1111 как текст и в B тоже текст( Сделал доп столбец: сцепил B и C столбец. мудрю с тем как подставить это к А

Comment: *Вариант_ошибки_2*: не верь глазам своим. Форматом ячеек данные могут быть приведены к одинаковому визуальному отображению, но на самом деле значения могут отличаться. Пример: формат - *Числовой*, 0 знаков после запятой. И 2,0, и 2,123 будут отображены, как 2

Comment: @Roman Ryzh, для чего сцеплять значения двух столбцов? Похоже, Вы неточно описали задачу и Вас неправильно поняли.

Comment: @vikttur Для того, чтобы поискать другие пути решения вопроса. Еще пробую ВПР, но пока пишу макрос...

Answer (score 0):

В столбец D впишите формулу **=ИНДЕКС($C$1:$C$4;ПОИСКПОЗ(A1;$B$1:$B$4;0);1)**
Диапазон 1--4 можете скорректировать по кол-ву строк с данными.